# How to use Youtube API v3 to upload video via Powershell

Tags: python, api, powershell, youtube, upload

I would like to automate a weekly upload of a video to our Youtube channel via Powershell script which I can schedule in Task Scheduler.
Is that possible ? 
I created a Project in the Google Developers Console.
I got myself a Client ID and Client secret for the Oauth.
And I saw examples in Java, Javascript, Python, .NET,... https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video.
But I got lost...
Anyone who could give me some practical tips ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found this interesting link :
https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload
I unzipped it, ran the setup. But when I try an upload, I get this error :
  File "D:\Python27\youtube-upload-master\youtube_upload\upload_video.py", line
10, in <module>
    from . import lib
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: I had to run the .bat file. Now the command starts. 
Still having other issues now...

Comment: I can confirm you that this solution on http://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload works fine !
Afterwards I can simply run the Python command from within Powershell !  Awesome  :-)

Comment: I just get  `raise ResponseNotReady()` errors

Comment: Can this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231543/python-httplib-responsenotready