# Youtube-upload error httplib.ResponseNotReady

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I'm a python user from China, using youtube-upload, when I run:

```
os.system('python upload_video.py --file=ts.flv --title="Video Title"')
```

Should open a link with youtube, and say the authentication flow has completed, but it says:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1108, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
httplib.ResponseNotReady
```

Is the reason the Great Firewall of China?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231543/python-httplib-responsenotready/3232999